# What does "X"stand for in "XARMAX"?

Tags: time-series

What does "X" stand for in "XARMAX"? I searched online but couldn't find it.

Is there "XARMA"?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you see this term used? First search result for me is a restaurant in Spain...

Comment: @Thomas: http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/intro-to-forecasting/doc_download/24-regression-vs-box-jenkins

Comment: @ Tim: this is not commonly used abbreviation in econometrics. So google didn't give you an answer

Comment: @Metrics I imagine that you are correct, but time series analysis is used very widely beyond econometrics, or even applied economics.

Comment: @Nick : Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

According to the only use of the term in [the document you provide](http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/intro-to-forecasting/doc_download/24-regression-vs-box-jenkins), the X stands for "regression":

> Multivariate Box-Jenkins is essentially a healthy marriage between Regression(X) and ARIMA. That is why it is sometimes referred to as XARMAX. When you add Intervention Detection into the mix you get a robust XARMAX model, the design goal of AUTOBOX.

Beats me...